# Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

I am having error with the Login.js code these are the error shown I am also having problem with the navigation in header please help me out this is a CRUD operation website.

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check your code at login.js:36.
    at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:482:75)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42128:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42571:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42509:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40827:5)
    at div
    at div
    at App
```

I am also having problem with the navigation in header please help me out this is a CRUD operation website.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Create from './components/create';
import Read from './components/read';
import Update from './components/update';
import Login from './components/login';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';                                                
// import Header from './components/header';

function App() {
  // let Navigate = useNavigate();

  return ( 
    <div>
    <header>
<h1 class='header1'>Aman Enterprises</h1>
<nav class ='nav'>
  <ul>
    {/* <li><Link to = '/login'>Login</Link></li> */}
    {/* <li><Link to = '/create'>Registration</Link></li> */}
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
    <div className="main">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Create />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="read" element={<Read />} />
          <Route path="update" element={<Update />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router'

export default function Login() {
    let navigate = useNavigate()

    const[username, setusername] = useState('');
    const[Employee_password, setEmployee_password] = useState('');
    
    const GetData = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault();
        console.log(username, Employee_password)


    if(username !== username && Employee_password !== Employee_password)
    {
        alert('Username or Password does not match!')
        return false
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/emp/login',{
        username,
        Employee_password
    }).then((res)=>{
        console.log('Login Successfull')
        navigate('/read')
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    }
return(
    <div>
        <Form onCLick={GetData}>
        <h2>Login into existing ID</h2>
        <Form.field>
            <label>Enter Username</label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Username' onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.field>
        <Form.field>
            <label>Passworld</label>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_password(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.field>
        {/* {<error && <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>Error</div>>} */}
        <Button type='submit'>Login</Button>
        </Form>
    </div>
 )
}
```

create.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

export default function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [Employee_name, setEmployee_name] = useState('');
    const [Employee_id, setEmployee_id] = useState('');
    const [Employee_address, setEmployee_address] = useState('');
    const [Employee_post, setEmployee_post] = useState('');
    const [username, setusername] = useState('');
    const [Employee_password, setEmployee_password] = useState('');   

    const postData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if(Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post, username, Employee_password.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Enter Employee Details to register!')
            return false
        }

        if(Employee_name.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Enter Employee Name!')
             return false
        }
        if(Employee_id.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Enter Employee id!')
            return false
        }
        if(Employee_address.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Enter Employee address!')
            return false
        }
        if(Employee_post.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Enter Employee Position!')
            return false
        }
        if(username.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Set Employee Username!')
            return false
        }
        if(Employee_password.length === 0)
        {
            alert('Set Employee Password!')
            return false
        }

        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/qo`, {
            Employee_name,
            Employee_id,
            Employee_address,
            Employee_post,
            username,
            Employee_password

        })
        .then(() => {
            navigate('/Login')
        })
    
        alert('Data Saved')
    }
    return (
        <div>            
            <Form className="create-form" onSubmit={e =>postData(e)}>
            <h2 class='Header'>Employee Registration form</h2>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Name</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Name' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_name(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee ID</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Employee ID' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_id(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Address</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Address' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_address(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Employee Position</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Position' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_post(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Create Username</label>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Username' onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field required={true}>
                    <label>Create Password</label>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_password(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button class='b2' onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

read.js(panel for database display having update and delete functionality)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Read() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/emp`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }, []);

    const setData = (data) => {
        let { Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post, username, Employee_password } = data;
  
        localStorage.setItem('Employee ID', Employee_id);

        navigate('/update')}

    const getData = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/emp`)
            .then((getData) => {
                setAPIData(getData.data);
            })
    }

    const onDelete = (data) => {

        const{Employee_id}=data
        if(Employee_id===0){
            alert("Employee id not found")
            return
        }
        const url=`http://localhost:5000/emp/${Employee_id}`
        axios.delete(url)
        .then((res) => {
            getData();
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        alert('Employee Deleted!')
    }


    const Data = () => {
            navigate('/')
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <h2>Registered Employees</h2>
        <div>
            <Table singleLine>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Position</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Username</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Password</Table.HeaderCell>             
                        
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Delete</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                    {APIData.map((data,index) => {
                        return (
                            <Table.Row key={index+""}>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_id}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_address}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_post}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.username}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_password}</Table.Cell>
                                
                                {/* <Link to='/update'> */}
                                    <Table.Cell> 
                                        <Button onClick={() => setData(data)}>Update</Button>
                                    </Table.Cell>
                                {/* </Link> */}
                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button onClick={() => onDelete(data)}>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>
                            </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
            <Button onClick={Data} type='submit'>Home</Button>
        </div>
        </form>
        
    )
}
```

update.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Update() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const [Employee_name, setEmployee_name] = useState('');
    const [Employee_id, setEmployee_id] = useState('');
    const [Employee_address, setEmployee_address] = useState('');
    const [Employee_post, setEmployee_post] = useState('');
    const [username, setusername] = useState('');
    const[Employee_password, setEmployee_password] = useState('');


    
    useEffect(() => {
        setEmployee_id(localStorage.getItem('Employee ID'));
        const id=localStorage.getItem('Employee ID')
        getEmplyeeDetailsById(id)

        
    }, []);

   const getEmplyeeDetailsById=(id)=>{
       const url=`http://localhost:5000/emp/${id}`
    axios.get(url)
        .then((res) =>{
if(res && res.data){
    console.log(res.data[0])
    let { Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post, username, Employee_password } =res.data[0];
    setEmployee_name(Employee_name)
    setEmployee_id(Employee_id)
    setEmployee_address(Employee_address)
    setEmployee_post(Employee_post)
    setusername(username)
    setEmployee_password(Employee_password)
    

}
            // setAPIData(update.data);
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
    const updateAPIData = () =>{
    let jsonData={
        Employee_name,
        Employee_id,
        Employee_address,
        Employee_post,
        username,
        Employee_password
    }
        axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/emp/update`, jsonData)
        .then(() => {
            navigate('/read')
        })
    }

    const back = () => {
        navigate('/read')
}


    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form">
            <h2>Update the Registered Data</h2>
            <Form.Field>
                    <label>Employee Name</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Name' value={Employee_name} onChange={(e) =>setEmployee_name(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Employee ID</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee ID' value={Employee_id+""} onChange={(e) => setEmployee_id(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Employee Address</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Address' value={Employee_address} onChange={(e) => setEmployee_address(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Employee Position</label>
                    <input placeholder='Employee Position' value={Employee_post} onChange={(e) => setEmployee_post(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input placeholder='username' value={username} onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_password(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit' onClick={updateAPIData}>Update</Button>
                <Button onClick={back} type='submit'>Back</Button> 
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo to me -> `<error &&` vs `error &&`

Comment: use useEffect when you have async logic, or better as suggested by react, use a dependency like redux toolkit, or even better, use redux toolkit query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Form.field` with `Form.Field`  in your Login.js

Answer (score 0):

In App.js You have to use '/' before every pathname. For example: path="/login".
In Login.js. Use  useEffect hook for execute function. Example:

```
useEffect(()=>{GetData () },[])
```

I hope it will useful for you

Comment: That will solve the navigation problem in the header part of the code but still I have the string issue React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.